# sonar-fortify-plugin is unable to show "Open Report" link

Tags: sonarqube, fortify

I am currently using sonar 4.3.3 and was able to install "sonar-fortify-plugin-2.0" on it.Thereafter I generated an fpr file for a corresponding git repo through Fortify (2.6 and 3.8) and uploaded it in on my sonar test instance. 
Sonar show's me the violation's but the below page also  shows "Open Report" link

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Fortify+Plugin

Can someone guide what needs to be done to get the "Open Report" link ?
Currently that is missing from my widget.

I have decomplied the sonar-fortify-plugin-2.0.jar and there in fortify.properties file I see

```
fortify.widget.openReport=Open Report
```

Hence assuming this plugin supports the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link "Open Report" does not exist in version 2.x. Screenshot in documentation is not up-to-date.

Note: no need to decompile JAR file. Sources of this open-source project are available at https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-fortify.

Comment: Thanks Simon.To add to the above query so the widget only will show number of violations and those numbers aren't clickable links.

Comment: Simon, which version supports this "Open Report" link ?

Comment: Unfortunately development of this plugin has been stopped due to lack of support from HP. I'm sorry but I can't help you on this topic.